# How to get the latest rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id      start       end
------------------------------        
1       2013-04-08  null
2       2013-04-01  null
2       2012-04-01  2013-04-01
3       2012-04-01  2013-04-01
4       2012-04-01  2013-04-01
4       2011-04-01  2012-04-01
```

I want to get such a table:

```
id  start       end
-----------------------------            
1   2013-04-08  null
2   2013-04-01  null
3   2012-04-01  2013-04-01
4   2012-04-01  2013-04-01
```

so I wish to get one row for each id with newest information.

How can I write the query?

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: @MattBall I have this question and no idea how to do it as a new sql beginner. so no research efforts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQL Server` supports `Common Table Expression` and `Windowing Functions`.  `ROW_NUMBER()` ranks the records for every group and which is the basis for the filtering of he records.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, [Start], [End],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [START] DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT ID, [Start], [End]
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1be2b/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up on J W's answer, you could also do it like this, which in my eyes are easier to figure out:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY start DESC) AS temp GROUP BY id;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY start DESC) AS temp GROUP BY id ORDER BY id;
```

this would do the same thing, so it depends on how you like the query, the last query sorts the outcome by the ID whereas the first doesn't.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/885cd/1